# Blank screen after grub when booting from live CD

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, kubuntu

I'm trying to install kubuntu to dual boot with windows 8 on my laptop from a CD I burned, but selecting any option from the grub menu causes a blank screen, and the CD drive stops after a short while. The MD5 of the .iso was correct and I ran the check utility on the CD on another computer and it found no errors. The other computer is also able to load the installer.

I found several dozen solutions to similar problems that haven't worked for me, most people seem to be able to get past the grub menu and get a black screen after they try to boot the OS. On the laptop I'm trying to install on, booting from the CD goes directly to the grub menu, with the options "Start kubuntu / OEM installation (for manufacturers) / Check disk for errors". Choosing any of these simply goes to a blank screen, and doesn't (seem to) read anything from the disk. Per [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743535), I tried changing the end of the linux boot command from `quiet splash` to `--verbose single`, but the example in that thread used a different boot command to begin with. I've also seen a lot of talk about `nomodeset`, but that seems to relate to something later in the process.

I have integrated graphics (on intel), and the disk is a DVD-R. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, right after I ask a question, I find the answer by accident.

I decided to see if the command line could help at all, so I tried running the `help` command, and got an error saying that secure boot prevented access to the command. So I tried again, opened up BIOS settings, and disabled secure boot - then everything worked fine. I guess secure boot was preventing grub from loading anything off of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've found that the live cd OS doesn't have all the drivers for random laptop screens (or trackpads), and to install ubuntu I first have to plug in an external display to the vga port which seems to be more reliable. Also, in general I find booting from live USB a lot more reliable than CDs but I guess you checked yours so maybe that's not it. Good luck.